# In PHP Remove Value of Attributes using Regex

Tags: php, regex

Say I have the following string:

```
<a name="anchor" title="anchor title">
```

Currently I can extract name and title with strpos and substr, but I want to do it right.  How can I do this with regex? And what if I wanted to extract from many of these tags within a block of text?

I've tried this regex:

```
/name="([A-Z,a-z])\w+/g
```

But it gets the name=" part as well, I just want the value.

Comment: Can do with RegEx, but would advise DOM reading if possible, faster. What is your code example of what you have tried?

Comment: You shouldn't be working with regex for this specific use case. I suggest referring to these docs: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: If you want to do it right use an HTML parser. Regex is not a sensible approach to parsing HTML.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: I'm actually parsing the data before the page is rendered so DOM is not possible, right?

Comment: No, See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The regex `(\S+)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?` can be used to extract all attributes

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument example:

```
<?php
$titles = array();
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br><a name="anchor" title="anchor title"></body></html>");
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
if ($links->length!=0) {
    foreach ($links as $a) {
        $titles[] = $a->getAttribute('title');
    }
}
?>
```

You commented: "I'm actually parsing the data before the page is rendered so DOM is not possible, right?"

We're working with the scraped HTML, so we construct a DOM with these functions and parse like XML.

Good examples in the comments here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php